# How to return collections based on neo4j node labels?

Tags: spring-boot, neo4j, cypher

I am not sure how to write a neo4j query that finds all nodes including the labels in a shortest path, and groups them by label in the output.

EDIT: The shortestPath includes links between Tags->Files->SubDirs->SourceDir and I want all of those linkages.

This neo4j syntax is wrong somewhere, but this is basically what I am trying to return to my java spring code

```
MATCH (a:Tag),(b:File),(c:SourceDir),
path = shortestPath((a)-[*]->(c))
WHERE a.name=~('(?i).*'+"READ"+'.*')
FOREACH (n IN NODES(path) |
WHERE label(n) = "SubDir" as dir |
WHERE label(n) = "SourceDir" as src |
WHERE label(n) = "File" as file |
WHERE label(n) = "Tag" as tag)
RETURN COLLECT(dir) as dirs, src as source, COLLECT(file) as file, COLLECT(tag) as tags
```

The java syntax portion looks like this, composed of both the neo4j query and the result

```
 @Query("MATCH (a:Tag),(b:File),(c:SourceDir), "
             + "path = shortestPath((a)-[*]->(c)) "
             + "WHERE a.name=~('(?i).*'+{search}+'.*') "
             + "FOREACH (n IN NODES(path) | "
             + "WHERE label(n) = 'SubDir' as dir | "
             + "WHERE label(n) = 'SourceDir' as src | "
             + "WHERE label(n) = 'File' as file | "
             + "WHERE label(n) = 'Tag' as tag) "
             + "RETURN COLLECT(dir) as dirs, src as source, COLLECT(file) as files, COLLECT(tag) as tags)")
  public List<ResultData> findByTag(@Param("search") String search);

@QueryResult
public class ResultData
{
   Set<File> files;
   Set<Directory> dirs;
   Source source;
   Set<Tag> tags;
}
```

What is the proper neo4j query to give me expected results?

Comment: Can you tell us what `(b:File)` is doing here? I don't see any usage `b` in the query, so this is creating a cross product for no good reason as far as I can tell.

Comment: Since `shortestPath()` would return, at most, a *single* path, why are you trying to collect all nodes with each label? Wouldn't a single path only have a single node with each label? Do you actually want to call `allShortestPaths()` or do something else?

Comment: Ther are muliple node labels in the single shortestPath that gets returned. The node labels include tags, files, subdirs, and end at sourcedir

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may work for you:

```
MATCH (a:Tag)
WHERE a.name=~('(?i).*'+"READ"+'.*')
MATCH p = shortestPath((a)-[*]->(c:SourceDir))
RETURN
  [n IN NODES(p) WHERE 'SubDir'    IN LABELS(n)] AS dirs,
  [n IN NODES(p) WHERE 'SourceDir' IN LABELS(n)] AS srcs,
  [n IN NODES(p) WHERE 'File'      IN LABELS(n)] AS files,
  [n IN NODES(p) WHERE 'Tag'       IN LABELS(n)] AS tags;
```

Note: A node can have multiple labels, so the above query will check every node for every label.

Comment: Another solution 
'MATCH (a:Tag {name: 'Readme'}),(b:SourceDir),
path = shortestPath((a)-[*..15]->(b))
RETURN [n in nodes(path) WHERE 'Tag' in labels(n) | labels(n) + properties(n)] as Tags,
    [n in nodes(path) WHERE 'File' in labels(n) | labels(n) + properties(n)] as Files,
    [n in nodes(path) WHERE 'SubDir' in labels(n) | labels(n) + properties(n)] as SubDirs,
    [n in nodes(path) WHERE 'SourceDir' in labels(n) | labels(n) + properties(n)] as SourceDirs'